# MobileHub where to store API keys

Tags: android, java-native-interface, amazon-cognito, api-key, aws-mobilehub

I am building an app based on the mobile hub sample app. The sample-app has the API keys stored in a class file AWSconfiguration:

```
public class AWSConfiguration {
    // AWS MobileHub user agent string
    public static final String AWS_MOBILEHUB_USER_AGENT =
            "MobileHub ********* aws-my-sample-app-android-v0.16";
    // AMAZON COGNITO
    public static final Regions AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION =
            Regions.fromName("us-east-1");
    public static String  AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID =     "us-east-************6";

    // Google Client ID for Web application
    public static  String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ="";//"*********************.apps.googleusercontent.com";


    public static final Regions AMAZON_DYNAMODB_REGION =
            Regions.fromName("us-east-1");
    public static  String AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID =   "************";


    public static  String AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID =   "*************";



    public static  String AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET =  "*************";

    private static final AWSMobileHelperConfiguration helperConfiguration = new AWSMobileHelperConfiguration.Builder()
            .withCognitoRegion(AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION)
            .withCognitoIdentityPoolId(AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID)
            .withCognitoUserPool(AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
                    AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID, AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET)
            .build();
    /**
     * @return the configuration for AWSKit.
     */
    public static AWSMobileHelperConfiguration getAWSMobileHelperConfiguration() {

        return helperConfiguration;
    }



}
```

**It seems unsafe to store the client secret key this way. What are the risks?**

I experiemnted with hiding the keys in JNI files but could not find the proper entry point in the activity to set the keys before they are called from the mobile helper.

Answer (score 2):

Storing in clear text is generally a bad idea, as you guessed. You could use the android keystore, store it encrypted (the stronger the key, the better), obfuscate it with some unique identifier of your device, or access it via some API you control and secure. It's possible to use some other solution, or a combination of the above possibilities. The final decision comes down to you and what your app needs/abilities are, but there's a few ways to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

[SharedPreferences.Editor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) can be a solution. 
Password or something like this are stored in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).